# is it possible to use identity server with asp.net core in shared host with "load user profile" = false?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, application-pool

I'm try to use asp.net core and react template with individual user account template in vs 2019.

but after publishing I noticed that "Load user profile" in application pool setting is set to false.

is it possible to use identity server with asp.net core in shared host with "load user profile" = false ?

I also tried to PersistKeysToFileSystem

```
services.AddDataProtection()
     .PersistKeysToFileSystem(newDirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));
```

but its not working.